# CYPHER: Unable to exclude nodes from a list using WHERE NOT ... IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am currently having trouble getting the WHERE NOT ... IN ... working. I am hoping to get a list of neighbour nodes, which have this "pool" relationship with the children, without including any of the original child nodes. At the moment if I use the command below, the returned neighbour list will contain children nodes.

```
MATCH (parent)-[r:Contains]-(children) WHERE parent.display_name='xyz'
WITH parent, r, children, collect(children) as child_list
OPTIONAL MATCH (children)-[:Pool]->(pool)<-[:Pool]-(neighbours) 
WHERE NOT neighbours IN child_list
RETURN child_list, collect(DISTINCT neighbours)
```

An alternative way of doing this would be, just exclude neighbours that are also immediately related to parent. However this also returns neighbours as a list containing the children, seemingly ignoring the [r] relationship. Although if I do WHERE NOT (neighbours)--(parent), this will exclude the children, but at the expense of relationships that are not [r], the current relationship I am looking at.

```
MATCH (parent)-[r:Contains]-(children) WHERE parent.display_name='xyz'
WITH parent, r, children, collect(children) as child_list
OPTIONAL MATCH (children)-[:Pool]->(pool)<-[:Pool]-(neighbours) 
WHERE NOT (neighbours)-[r]-(parent)
RETURN child_list, collect(DISTINCT neighbours)
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone can take a look at either of the options, and can help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

In your queries, I believe that the aggregation functions differently from what you are expecting.

`WITH parent, r, children, collect(children) as child_list` is going to return a row per child, and not a row per parent with a collection of children for that parent.
The reason is that not only `parent`, but also `r` and `children` are considered grouping keys, and so this boils down to a unique key for every combination of `parent`,`r` and `children`, and hence different rows (where `collect(children)` has one element only, the child)

```
MATCH (parent)-[r:Contains]-(children) WHERE parent.display_name='xyz'
WITH parent, children
OPTIONAL MATCH (children)-[:Pool]->(pool)<-[:Pool]-(neighbours) 
WHERE NOT neighbours=children
RETURN collect(children), collect(DISTINCT neighbours)
```

could be closer to what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This should return a list of parent `xyz`'s children, and a list of neighbors that are in the same "pools" as those children.

```
MATCH (parent)-[:Contains]-(child) WHERE parent.display_name='xyz'
WITH COLLECT(child) as child_list
UNWIND child_list AS c
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:Pool]->(pool)<-[:Pool]-(neighbor) 
WHERE NOT neighbor IN child_list
RETURN child_list, COLLECT(DISTINCT neighbor) AS neighbors
```